# MPMoviePlayerViewController Issue-Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to implement the movie player for that,i'm using MPMoviePlayerViewController.

**My code is,**

```
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL]; 

moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming; 
[self presentModalViewController:moviePlayerController animated:YES]; 
[[moviePlayerController moviePlayer] play];
```

but it's continuously loading and not playing the video.What i'm wrong with my code.

**My requirement is,**

In the movie player,when i'm click on the done button it goes to the page which i'm starting from.

Thank you for your consideration and effort

**Edit:**

Any sample code for using MPMoviePlayerController instead of using MPMoviePlayerViewController please give me.(please give me your implemented sample code because i can't understand the tutorial code)please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aaa" ofType:@"mp4"];  
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];  
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)]; 
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];  
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;  
[moviePlayerController play];
```